# Acceptation of "acceptation"

Tags: meaning, nouns

What may be the meaning of the word ***acceptation*** for general English usage?

The [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acceptation) lists primary definition as  "1: *acceptance*; especially : favorable reception or approval" and follows on with "2: a generally *accepted* meaning of a word or understanding of a concept"

[Oxforddictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/acceptation) online lists only one definition: "*noun* a particular sense or the generally recognized meaning (**common acceptation**) of a word or phrase."

The [OAADonline](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/acceptation) too records just one entry: "(*linguistics*) the meaning that a word or expression is generally accepted as having".

Would it be acceptable to use the word *acceptation* in the sense of *acceptance*, as in: 
"acceptation/rejection of a paper submitted to a conference"?

Comment: @AndrewLeach :) "generally accepted meaning".

Comment: My question is entirely different -- Would you mind if I ask you to give it another read?

Comment: You have asked two questions, one at the start and one at the end. The answer to the second question informs the answer to the first. And the second question can't be answered without clarification of exactly what is meant by *acceptation* in that phrase.

Comment: It's not acceptable in most formal circumstances (newspaper, journal). In informal instances, it's barely recognizable.

Answer (score 7):

*Acceptation* has been in use for centuries, but in contemporary usage it seems to have no advantage over *acceptance*, and the distinct disadvantage that it is unusual, and as such likely to be a distraction.

Comment: I find this rather strange. You seem to mean *acceptation* in the sense of *acceptance* would be a distraction -- certainly not in the sense of "generally accepted meaning".

Comment: I was answering your question about whether _acceptation_ would be acceptable in describing a paper submitted to a conference.

Comment: I would never use it _in lieu of_ "acceptance" vs. "rejection" of a paper for a conference. This is standard parlance in the conference trade, and using "acceptation" would come off as pretentious at best, even more so than using _in lieu of_.

Answer (score 7):

I'd be *fairly* happy for this picture from the [Wiltshire Times](http://www.thisiswiltshire.co.uk/news/9915603.Devizes_MP_hands_in_internet_safety_petition_to_No__10_Downing_Street/)

[image: Devizes MP at 10 Downing Street]

to be captioned "Acceptation of petition at Prime Minister's office" because that is the act of accepting that box of paperwork. I would find it distracting because it's unusual and could equally well — in fact more than equally well — be the acceptance of the petition.

I *wouldn't* be happy with a sentence like "Our acceptation of the necessity for a new airport depends on [whatever]" because that's not really the same act. That should be ***acceptance***. There's a subtle difference between the physical act in the photo and what is a metaphysical act in accepting a particular philosophical argument, where the necessity is accepted as a fact.

Because that's such a subtle difference I'd far rather keep both of the above as *acceptance*.

If you're asking about the definition of the word *acceptation* in a linguistic sense then it means what it means: it's a technical term with a specific definition, "the meaning that a word or expression is generally accepted as having". It wouldn't be right to use *acceptance* instead of that technical term.